# Auto join in prometheus with max over time with no output

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator

prometheus:v2.15.2
kubernetes:v1.14.9

I have a query where it shows exactly the maximum over time during the set period. 
But I would like to join with the metric already set in the kube_pod_container resource.

I would like to know if what is set is close to the percentage set or not, displaying the percentage.

I have other examples working with this same structure of metric

`jvm_memory_bytes_used{instance="url.instance.com.br"} / jvm_memory_bytes_max{area="heap"} * 100 > 80`

but this one is not working.

`max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="pod-name-here",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [1h:1s]) / kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores * 100 < 70`

Well the first idea was to create a query to collect the maximum historical cpu usage of a container in a pod in a brief period:

`max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="xpto-92838241",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [1h:1s])`

**Element**: {} **Value:** 0.25781324101515

If we execute it this way:

`container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="xpto-92838241",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}`

**Element:** container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type="t3.small",beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",cluster="teste.k8s.xpto",container="xpto",container_name="xpto",cpu="total",failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_region="sa-east-1",failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_zone="sa-east-1c",generic="true",id="/kubepods/burstable/poda9999e9999e999e9-/99999e9999999e9",image="nginx",instance="kubestate-dev.internal.xpto",job="kubernetes-cadvisor",kops_k8s_io_instancegroup="nodes",kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",kubernetes_io_hostname="ip-99-999-9-99.sa-east-1.compute.internal",kubernetes_io_os="linux",kubernetes_io_role="node",name="k8s_nginx_nginx-99999e9999999e9",namespace="nmpc",pod="pod-92838241",pod_name="pod-92838241",spot="false"} **Value:** 22533.2

Now we have what is configured:

`kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{pod="xpto-92838241"}`

**Element:** kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="xpto",instance="kubestate-dev.internal.xpto",job="k8s-http",namespace="nmpc",node="ip-99-999-999-99.sa-east-1.compute.internal",pod="pod-92838241"} **Value:** 1

Well, in my perception it would be to use these two metrics and get it close to the percentage like this:

`max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="xpto-dev-92838241",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [1h:1s]) / kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores * 100 < 70`

**Element:** *no data* **Value:**

But these two metrics do not interact, I can not understand why and do not find in the documentation.

Regards

Comment: What version of kubernetes are you using ?

Comment: prometheus:v2.15.2
kubernetes:v1.14.9

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.16.md#removed-metrics), only in **Kubernetes 1.16** *cadvisor metric labels `pod_name` and `container_name`* were removed and substituted by `pod` and `container` respectively.
As you are using **Kubernetes 1.14**, you should still use `pod_name` and `container_name`.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the info.
I can get the metrics with separate queries, but I can't get them to interact.

Comment: Well the first idea was to create a query to collect the maximum historical cpu usage of a container in a pod in a brief period:

`max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="xpto-92838241",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [1h:1s])`
Element: {} Value: 0.25781324101515

Comment: If we execute it this way:
`container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="xpto-92838241",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}`

Comment: Updated issue with output elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Prometheus Operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/), 
with the documentation and this blog about [CPU aggregation walkthrough](https://medium.com/@amimahloof/kubernetes-promql-prometheus-cpu-aggregation-walkthrough-2c6fd2f941eb).

I got the solution of my problem with vector matching.

`max_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="pod-name-here",container_name!="POD", container_name!=""}[1m])) [1h:1s]) / on(pod_name) group_left(container_name) kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{pod="pod-name-here"}`

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The following PromQL query returns per-pod CPU usage in percentage of its configured limits:

```
100 * sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (pod)
  /
sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu"}) by (pod)
```

The following query returns the maximum per-pod CPU usage over the last hour:

```
max_over_time((
  100 * sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by 
  (pod)
    /
  sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu"}) by (pod)
)[1h:5m])
```

Note that the first query is basically wrapped into `max_over_time((...)[1h:5m])`. Such construction is called [subquery](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#subqueries). It may work slower than the original query.